# Passing a Generic Type Using Fully Qualified Class Name And Reflection

Tags: c#

I get the `'objType' is a variable but is used like a type` compiler error when I try the following code:

```
Type objType = Type.GetType(objFullyQualifiedName);
object jsonObj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<objType> (jsonString);
```

How can I pass the type I obtain from the fully qualified class name to the DeserializeObject method?

Answer (score 0):

There is a non-generic version of `DeserializeObject()` that takes an instance of `Type` as an argument. The generic versions ultimately call this non-generic method, so the result should be the same.

[Reference](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm)

Note that if such a method were not available, you could still call the generic version using reflection (compiling a dynamic method to improve performance, if needed).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that non-generic method, I will use that. Could you also provide an example of how I would be able to call the generic version if possible?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-do-i-use-reflection-to-call-a-generic-method